# Proof verification: One independent set implies that the other set is also independent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, solution-verification

**Question:** Given the vectors $v_{1},...,v_{k}$ in $R^{n}$ and an m x n-matrix A. Prove that if H={A$v_{1}$,...,A$v_{k}$} is independent, then so is W={$v_{1},...,v_{k}$}.

**My proof:** I will prove the contrapositive. Suppose that W is dependent, then it holds that the equations $x_{1}*v_{1} + ... + x_{k}*v_{k}$=$0$ has more solutions besides $x_{1}=...=x_{k}=0$. Suppose that $x_{1}=a_{1},...,x_{k}=a_{k}$ is a solution of the equation with at least one of the $a_{i}$ unequal to $0$. We see the folowing:
$a_{1}*Av_{1} + ... + a_{k}*Av_{k}$<-> A($a_{1}*v_{1} + ... + a_{k}*v_{k}$)=A*$0$=$0$, and this implies that H is dependent, thus proven the statement.

Is my proof correct? Note that in some situations I mean the zero matrix with $0$ and some the number $0$, this depends on the context of the sentence (I don't know how I can put in a sign for the zero-matrix here)

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's correct. It is common to use $0$ for the zero scalar, the zero vector, the zero matrix, the zero everything simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

> Suppose $H$ is linearly independent and suppose $a_1,\dots,a_k \in \mathbb R$ satisfy $a_1v_1 + \cdots + a_kv_k = 0$. Then
> $$0 = A0 = A(a_1v_1 + \cdots + a_kv_k) = a_1Av_1 + \cdots a_kAv_k$$
> and by assumption, this implies $a_1 = \cdots = a_k = 0$. Therefore $W$ is also linearly independent.